# How to use the system date or current date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

For example, in a database "Library", I want to get the book titles, borrower's name and address, in a branch called "`Sharpstown`" whose due date is today?

This is how I did the select statement --

```
SELECT BOOK.Title,BORROWER.Name, BORROWER.Address
FROM BORROWER,BOOK,LIBRARY_BRANCH,BOOK_LOANS
WHERE BOOK.BookID = BOOK_LOANS.BookID AND
      LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchID = BOOK_LOANS.BranchID AND 
      BOOK_LOANS.CardNo = BORROWER.CardNo AND
      LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = 'Sharpstown' AND 
      BOOK_LOANS.DueDate = now() -- This is where I want to compare the dates
```

The Error is:

> 'now' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server, use `getDate()` instead of `now()`. You might have an additional issues depending on the data type of `BOOK_LOANS.DueDate`, so you might have to `CAST`:

```
... and CAST(BOOK_LOANS.DueDate as date) = CAST(getDate() as date)
```

The "`date`" type in SQL Server has granularity/precision of a day. By default `getDate()` returns a value of "`datetime`" type, which has granularity/precision of a millisecond.

Comment: thanks I have to learn more about cast and dates. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `NOW` in SQL Server. In SQL Server, we have `GETDATE()`

```
SELECT BOOK.Title,BORROWER.Name, BORROWER.Address
FROM BORROWER,BOOK,LIBRARY_BRANCH,BOOK_LOANS
WHERE BOOK.BookID = BOOK_LOANS.BookID 
  AND LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchID = BOOK_LOANS.BranchID 
  AND BOOK_LOANS.CardNo = BORROWER.CardNo 
  AND LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchName = 'Sharpstown' 
  AND BOOK_LOANS.DueDate = CONVERT(DATE, CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(12)), 105)
```

Comment: Both the answers worked @Paresh , but can you explain that why did you use datatypes here?

Comment: When you just run this CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(12)), you will get only date with time as 00:00:00:000

Comment: Oh thanks @paresh sir. Another sql lesson to add to my notebook :)